# Problems with print statment

Tags: python, printing

I am 100% new to programming and I'm having trouble practising the print hello world statement. My code is as follows:

```
  print(hello world!)
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Wrap `hello world!` with `'`: `print('hello world!')`.

Comment: Missing `'` in the statement

Comment: A bit of advice: **read the error message**. It probably showed something like "_Invalid syntax_". From there, you could have either searched for the correct syntax for `print` or for the meaning of "_Invalid syntax_" when using `print`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `''` or `""` that need to wrap around any string object in Python

Try:

```
print('Hello World!')
```

You may find [this documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_strings.asp) useful.